# Output commands sent to SauceLabs from protractor

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, protractor, saucelabs

Is there a way I can output each command on the console before it's sent to SauceLabs?

I have e2e tests that started failing with

> Command timed out after 90 seconds

after I upgraded my protractor version to the latest *4.0.8*

I'd like to find out which was the last command sent successfully to SauceLabs.